# Incorrect detection of TextViews at a specific position

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to create a simple mini-game in my app, but I have a problem detecting which view the user is touching.

This video will best explain my problem: https://www.youtube.com/shorts/x3TwS5MVh7o

I have tested a few things and I found out that for the fullscreen activity it works perfectly, but how can I solve this problem if I don't want this activity to be performed in full screen?

I made this activity fullscreen by adding this code:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Here is my code:

Activity

```
public class GameDrawActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static Path path = new Path();
    public static Paint paint_brush = new Paint();
    static Rect outRect = new Rect();
    static int[] location = new int[2];

    static TextView[] views;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_draw);

        ConstraintLayout cl_container = findViewById(R.id.cl_container);
        int childNumber = cl_container.getChildCount();
        views = new TextView[childNumber];

        for(int i=0;i<childNumber;i++){
            views[i] = (TextView) cl_container.getChildAt(i);
        }
    }

    public static void findView(int x, int y){
        for(View view : views){
            if(isViewInBounds(view, x, y)){
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

                return;
            }
        }
    }

    private static boolean isViewInBounds(View view, int x, int y){
        view.getDrawingRect(outRect);
        view.getLocationOnScreen(location);
        outRect.offset(location[0], location[1]);
        return outRect.contains(x, y);
    }
}
```

Display

```
public class Display extends View {
    public static ArrayList<Path> pathList = new ArrayList<>();

    ...

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                path.moveTo(x,y);
                invalidate();
                return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    path.lineTo(x,y);
                    pathList.add(path);
                    invalidate();
                    GameDrawActivity.findView((int)x,(int)y);
                    return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        for(int i=0;i<pathList.size();i++){
            paint_brush.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            canvas.drawPath(pathList.get(i), paint_brush);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Removed `android-studio` tag as that tag is for questions/issues with the Android Studio product. Your question has nothing to do with the Android Studio product.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Y coordinate is off by the height of the status bar. So you need to factor the height of the status bar into the calculations. You should be able to determine the height of the status bar by getting the location of the `ConstraintLayout` and using its Y Coordinate.